# Exposing Salt Metrics to Grafana

Tags: devops, metrics, grafana, salt-stack, exporter

I want to monitor my saltstack states and display it on grafana.

I am using salt 2017.7.4 and grafana 5.1

I want to be able to show the status of successful and unsuccessful states, latency, number of minions on every master/syndic, etc..

Is there a way to do that ? because i know there aren't any exporters available for it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently released an open-source project that integrates Salt and Grafana and addresses some of your questions (success rate, latency): https://turtletraction-oss.gitlab.io/salt-grafana/

[image: overview dashboard]

[image: job view]

Comment: Great job, is it possible to use it with self-hosted stack ?

Comment: @Peacefull I haven't tried that, but it should be possible. If you find any issues with a self-hosted Grafana stack, feel free to submit them at https://gitlab.com/turtletraction-oss/salt-grafana/-/issues

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to use a returner module + output to some kind of database. Grafana is actually just a query/display engine. The carbon returner would work, but you would need to setup graphite (a database).

Once you set that up, you can then use grafana to query the graphite database.

[Salt Carbon Returner](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.carbon_return.html#module-salt.returners.carbon_return)

[Carbon Server](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon)

Comment: do you know if carbon integrates with other types of database, like elastic-search ?